# how to add nl2br function to text widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I made my own theme. Quite simple. At the footer I add sidebar, which displays text widget.
And it is working fine... until I have one line.

How to add to sidebar function, or how to modify content of the widget, to get function nl2br or something simillar - changing 'enter' to '
'

Simple adding nl2br(dynamic_sidebar()) not working, 
also dynamic_sidebar(nl2br(..));

I have try to add to my function.php code.. but I mess with something (probybly with $sidebar).

```
  add_filter('sidebar-1', 'newLines');

  function newLines($sidebar) {

  $sidebar = nl2br($sidebar);

  return $sidebar;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `widget_text` filter

```
function filter_text($text) {
    return nl2br($text);
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'filter_text');
```